# issue on adding all day event

Tags: android, android-intent, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am Adding all day event in calendar more then 1 day example "2015-02-27T00:00:00+00:00" to  "2015-02-28T00:00:00+00:00"

Problem is : It add only in 27 not 28 because of time is 00:00. I want to add in 27 and 28 both.

code is

```
     public static void addToCalendar(Context context, String title,
        String description, String location, long timeStart, long timeEnd,boolean allDay, String id ) {
    // Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(true) + "events");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("calendar_id", 1);
    values.put("title", title);
    //values.put("allDay", 0);
    values.put("dtstart", timeStart);
    values.put("dtend", timeEnd); 
    values.put("description", "");
    values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
    values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, true);  
    String timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    values.put("eventTimezone", timeZone);
    Uri ur = getCalendarURI(true);  
    context.getContentResolver().insert(ur, values);

}
```

Comment: please revise Your question in a way that everybody can understand this. And what´s the issue? Got any errors in the logcat? If Yes, please post it...

Comment: Not getting any error updated question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add from "2015-02-27T00:00:00+00:00" to "2015-02-29T00:00:00+00:00"

**OR**

Add from "2015-02-27T00:00:00+00:00" to "2015-02-28T23:59:59+00:00"

both will add 27 and 28 whole day event

Comment: Can you please guide me why I should add till 29, I am getting "2015-02-27T00:00:00+00:00" to "2015-02-28T00:00:00+00:00" date from API. is any logical issue or what? and also If time mentioned then what should I do?

Comment: If time is mentioned like "2015-02-27T16:15:00+00:00" to "2015-03-01T16:15:00+00:00" then what should I do and please let me know if any documentations has available to add 59 minute and 59 second are available. Thanks for quick feedback.